# Auth firebase onAuthStateChange

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When the user logs in successfully, I get redirected to my main page (which I want), but it keeps refreshing all the time. Any idea what the reason could be?

**Code:**

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

    if(user){
        console.log('user is signed in', user);
        window.location='/';

    }else{
        console.log('user is NOT signed in');

    }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by it keep refreshing all the time?

Comment: its so strange, the browser keeps on refreshing the page...its like window.location='/' keeps getting called every half a second

Answer (score 0):

A guess; could be because the code gets executed again after the page are loaded and keeps redirecting? if that is the case you could wrap a if or make sure that the code only are embedded on the login page.

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

if(user){
    console.log('user is signed in', user);
    if(window.location.href != "/"){
        window.location='/';
    }

}else{
    console.log('user is NOT signed in');

}

})
```

Comment: Yes, that was my thought, but what would i put in the if statement?

Comment: logIn() { </br>
             console.log('this.STATE:', this.state);

             const {email, password} = this.state;

             firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
     password).catch(error => {
                 this.setState({error})

                 //TODO functionality for redirect to /app when login success, stay 
     on login of failed
             }).then(function () { if(firebaseApp){
                 window.location = '/';
             }else {
                 window.location='/signin'

             }


             })
         }

Comment: i though if i put 5 spaces in front of my code its will recognise it as code...how can i make that happen in a comment? thx in advance

Comment: did you try the if statment from the code i wrote ? and for code i dont believe you can get it to look as nice with indents in the comments, but if you use backticks around your `code` it will be the same grey color.

Comment: thx you for your feedback, the onAuthStateChange above is in my index.js.  i tried to move it to my login.js but same result -> keeps on refreshing constantly. I have done this now ->  ^ firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(error => {
            this.setState({error})

            //TODO functionality for redirect to /app when login success, stay on login of failed
        }).then(function () { if(firebaseApp){
            window.location = '/';
        }else {
            window.location='/signin'

        }
        })^

Comment: but then i dont know what to put in the if() clause, at the moment its obviously  always true @keja